# pq: invalid input syntax for type integer: ""

Tags: go, crud

i was trying to get id value from the URL with the help of chi.URLParam which I have assigned to id value, after getting id value from value i want to perform database operation with id value,so i was sending id value to

```
d.DB.Query("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id=$1", id)
```

but id returns nil data means id:=" ".

Handler

```
func GetOne(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    id := chi.URLParam(r, "id")
    fmt.Println("id is :", id)
    slc := data.GetOneEmp(id)
    out, err := json.MarshalIndent(slc, "", "   ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write(out)
}
```

Database function

```
func GetOneEmp(id int) []m.Employees {
    rows, err := d.DB.Query(`SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id=$1`, id)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        //return
    }
    var item m.Employees
    var slc []m.Employees
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        err = rows.Scan(&item.ID, &item.Name, &item.Rank, &item.Address, &item.Salary)
        //show status as well
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            //return everywhere when you get an error
        }
        slc = append(slc, item)
    }
    return slc
}
```

Comment: Please show full code with imports. BTW you can use `r.URL.Query().Get("id")` to get id params.

Comment: If `id := chi.URLParam(r, "id")` results in an empty string, i.e. `id` contains `""`, then that means that either no id was supplied in the request's URL path, or the router pattern, specified during handler registration, does not contain `{id}`. Either fix how you are sending the request, or fix how you are registering the handler.

Comment: i have updated my code here

Comment: http://localhost:8080/employees/getone/2 - URL

Comment: chi.URLParam returns a string but GetOneEmp takes an int, so this code shouldn't compile.

Comment: @Peter-I have converted string to int and passed the code now, still, I get the empty string into id